# How do I save outfits in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In *GTA Online*, I already know that you usually are only able to save outfits when you have an apartment/house. However, I was wondering whether you are able to save outfits into your base outfits without having to buy an apartment.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily do that!

- Go into the Outfits Menu **(CLOSET)** **OR** Go to store and **press** Square (If on PS3/PS4)

You can also **name your outfit** and save it to the list. There are about 10 save slots for outfits so far. More than enough, I think! For the XBOX consoles, just switch around the buttons.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Odd, I just checked that my PS4 copy is up to date but I don't have this ability at all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you go to a store go near the person at the cash register and talk to him/her (e on pc) and then just press spacebar to view your saved outfits or to save a new one.